# Good ideas for debugging Hibernate Session/Transaction errors?

Tags: hibernate, debugging, transactions, hibernate-session

I've used Hibernate for a little while now and have become accustomed to most of the common error messages. Most point me straight to the problem, but I've been having issues with this one:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session
```

I understand the error (the session has two different objects with the same ID), but I don't really know of a good way to debug my code to find the source of the issue. Usually, I look at the code that I'm currently changing and look for places where I load one object and manually create another, hoping that I can find a simple error in my logic. However, I'm currently working with a code set that I didn't write, that am not familiar with, and that has no documentation. The only solution that I can think of is to go through the code, line by line, hoping to find the error. Do you know of a better way to debug this error?

Additionally, the exact error that I'm getting is from a call to `saveOrUpdate()`, which makes me wonder if it is calling `save()` when it should be calling `update()`. Is there any way to look at the objects that Hibernate has in the current Session for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`saveOrUpdate` calls `update` if the detached entity already has an ID. `update` then tries to attach the given detached entity to the session. Since you can only have one instance of a given entity in the session, if you already have loaded the entity (using a `load`, a `get` or a query) in the session at the time `saveOrUpdate` is called, you'll get this exception.

`saveOrUpdate` should generally be one of the first things to do after opening a session. If you have to load the entity before updating it, you should use `merge`. I generally prefer using `merge` in all cases, because it's less error-prone.

You can have an idea of what's in the session using `session.getStatistics().getEntityKeys()`.

Comment: "And update tries to attach the given detached entity to the session." Shouldn't that say *save* instead of *update*?

Comment: No. Save makes a transient instance persistent, and attaches the entity to the session. Update takes a detached, modified instance and tries to attach it to the session. If there is already a persistent instance with the same ID in the session, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to set a breakpoint in the Session.Flush function and check which objects are stored in the persister. [Here](http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/debugging-nhibernate-session/) you may find some information how to track session-open and session-close events  - you probably need to carefully examine the `PersistenceContext` property of the `SessionImpl` object and the `OnFlush` event.

To debug with the source code, you don't need to recompile all NHibernate sources - you may bind pdb files with the zip source file (have a look at http://lowleveldesign.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/debugging-nhibernate-prepare-symbol-files/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not using nhibernate. I'll still look into using your advice in a Java context.